# phpcs rule or sniff for detecting usage of the "ksm()" or "kint()" function?

Tags: 8

Would it be possible for my local PHPCS standard to warn me when I use certain PHP functions like `kint()` or `ksm()`? It's not part of the Drupal Standard but I'm running a modified version with some improvements like this.

Comment: Create a custom ruleset and pass the filename to phpcs with `--standard=custom_ruleset.xml`. `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom">
<rule ref="Generic.PHP.ForbiddenFunctions">
  <properties>
    <property name="forbiddenFunctions" type="array">
      <element key="kint" value="null"/>
      <element key="ksm" value="null"/>
    </property>
  </properties>
</rule>
</ruleset>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by Checking Drupal coding standards. You can configure PHP code sniffer to check for Drupal coding standards by following the instructions from https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/code-review-module/installing-coder-sniffer and https://www.drupal.org/node/1587138

**Edit**: It turns out you can not identify all the debugging functions with standard Drupal Coding standard functions.In my testing drupalcs was able to identify only `dpm()`and `dsm()` functions but not `ksm()` or `kint()` .

There is an alternative way to identify debugging functions. You can add pre-commit hook to identify the debugging functions.

You can add the below script to git hooks.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Git pre-commit hook that prevents code that is not Drupal coding standard compliant of being committed.
#
# Fork of https://git.io/fNXBi by Dave Hall http://davehall.com.au
#

# Fetch the list of files that have changed.
FILES="$(git diff --staged --name-only HEAD --diff-filter=ACMRUXB)"

echo "Running PHP lint check" >&2
LINT_FAIL=0
for filename in $FILES; do
  if ! php -l $filename; then
    LINT_FAIL=1
  fi
done;

# There is no point in running PHP Code Sniffer on broken files.
if [ $LINT_FAIL -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Commit aborted. Fix your code. Then 'git add' and 'git commit' again."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Running PHP Code Sniffer Checks" >&2
echo $FILES | xargs phpcs --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,*.md
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 # Exit executing the git commit.
 exit 0
else
  # Ask what to do, not executing the commit. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121255/139407
  read -p "Fix the marked Sniff violations automatically [Y/n]?" line </dev/tty
  case "$line" in
    y|Y) echo $FILES | xargs phpcbf --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor,*.md
      ;;
    *) echo "No automatic corrections made."
      ;;
  esac

  echo "Commit aborted. Make remaining manual code fixes if necessary. Then 'git add' and 'git commit' again."
  exit 1
fi
```

Source : [Drupal git pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/lolandese/84173dbcfbcde534e7cd84a2f4a0b7b2)

[image: debug functions list]

[image: git pre commit hook]

[image: Drupal coding standards]

Comment: Yes? The code sniffer for Drupal coding standards checks for the existence of debugging functions in the code?

Comment: Yes , I will warn you with a message saying usage of dpm/ksm is discouraged.

Comment: Will edit my answer with a screenshot once I am at PC.

Comment: Cool, thank you for clarifying! 

Comment: If the Drupal standard can detect dpm(), then we should be able to modify it to also detect ksm(), no? I'm just having trouble finding documentation on how to identify functions. I believe it's a PHP class that needs to extended...

Comment: Thanks for offering a workaround, but the question was to leverage PHPCS, not a git hook.

Comment: @atwixtor – Sounds like a feature request then.

Answer (score 0):

Found the list of "discouraged functions" here:

`vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer/Drupal/Sniffs/Functions/DiscouragedFunctionsSniff.php`

So this class can simply be extended or modified directly, and PHPCS will warn about any other function you add to this list:

```php
<?
class DiscouragedFunctionsSniff extends ForbiddenFunctionsSniff
{

    /**
     * A list of forbidden functions with their alternatives.
     *
     * The value is NULL if no alternative exists, i.e., the function should
     * just not be used.
     *
     * @var array<string, null>
     */
    public $forbiddenFunctions = [
                                     // Devel module debugging functions.
        'dargs'               => null,
        'dcp'                 => null,
        'dd'                  => null,
        'dfb'                 => null,
        'dfbt'                => null,
        'dpm'                 => null,
        'dpq'                 => null,
        'dpr'                 => null,
        'dprint_r'            => null,
        'drupal_debug'        => null,
        'dsm'                 => null,
        'dvm'                 => null,
        'dvr'                 => null,
        'kdevel_print_object' => null,
        'kpr'                 => null,
        'kprint_r'            => null,
        'sdpm'                => null,
                                  // Functions which are not available on all
                                  // PHP builds.
        'fnmatch'             => null,
                                  // Functions which are a security risk.
        'eval'                => null,
    ];
}
```

[image: Working sniff]

Comment: Definitely not modified directly. But would be interested from where to extend it.

Comment: I believe it can be done by following this guide https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2017/11/06/catching-debug-statements-in-php/  @leymannx